# Android HttpURLConnection unable to send post data

Tags: java, php, android, http, post

There are literally dozens of Stack Overflow entries with titles like this, and yet in all of them the problem does not seem applicable, and the example solutions look like my code. The question is: why does the following not seem to send data via post to the web page.

Expected behavior: pressing the "test" button in the activity causes the following output:

```
{timestamp}/com.example.test D/Test: url: http://data.cubscout.local/enter_game_design
{timestamp}/com.example.test D/Test: json sent
{timestamp}/com.example.test D/Test: http response code: 200
{timestamp}/com.example.test D/Test: {"test_value":"test"}
{timestamp}/com.example.test D/Test: result read
```

in logcat and for `{"test_value":"test"}` to be printed in the error log for the page.

Actual Behaviour: pressing the "test" button in the activity causes the following output:

```
{timestamp}/com.example.test D/Test: url: http://data.cubscout.local/enter_game_design
{timestamp}/com.example.test D/Test: json sent
{timestamp}/com.example.test D/Test: http response code: 200
{timestamp}/com.example.test D/Test: result read
```

in logcat and a line is printed to the error log for the webpage that is just a timestamp

**Edit:** Note that using a command like `curl` to send the data causes the expected behavior. Eg. `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d {"test_value":"test"} http://da/enter_game_design/`
 causes `{"test_value":"test"}` to be recieved by curl and printed in the log This leads me to conclude that, even if the code to receive the server response has an issue, the code to send the data in the first place is broken.

**Edit 2:** I have tested that `Log.d("Test", IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream()));` will indeed print output to the log correctly by changing the url to another page

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by trevor on 12/5/16.
 */

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button testButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new AsyncUploadTest().execute();
            }
        });
    }
    private class AsyncUploadTest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>
    {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... v) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://data.cubscout.local/enter_game_design");

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                Log.d("Test","url: "+connection.getURL());

                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);

                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write("{\"test_value\":\"test\"}");
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();

                Log.d("Test","json sent");

                int httpResult = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("Test","http response code: "+httpResult);
                if(httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    Log.d("Test", IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream()));
                    Log.d("Test", "result read");
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("Test","exception while sending data to server",e);
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                Log.e("Test","exception while sending data to server",e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Test","exception while sending data to server",e);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (layout file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Test">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

the php script for the webpage being accessed

```
<?php
    $inputString = file_get_contents("php://input");
    error_log($inputString);
    echo $inputString;
?>
```

Comment: FWIW and unrelated: there is no charset parameter on application/json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `HttpURLConnection` first connects, the response code is `301 moved permanently`. This is because the url lacks an ending `/`. `HttpURLConnection` transparently remakes the connection with the url provided by the first connection, but does not resend the post data. Fixing the issue in this case is straightforward: add the slash in myself. Given the behavior of `HttpURLConnection` I would recommend handling redirects yourself for POST requests by doing the following:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://data.cubscout.local/enter_game_design");
    boolean redirect = false;

    do {
        redirect = false;
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        Log.d("Test","url: "+connection.getURL());

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write("{\"test_value\":\"test\"}");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        Log.d("Test","json sent");

        int httpResult = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("Test","http response code: "+httpResult);
        if(httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            Log.d("Test", IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream()));
            Log.d("Test", "result read");
        }
        else if(   httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                || httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                || httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER){
            redirect = true;
            url = new URL(connection.getHeaderField("Location"));
        }
    } while (redirect);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    Log.e("Test","exception while sending data to server",e);
} catch (ProtocolException e) {
    Log.e("Test","exception while sending data to server",e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Test","exception while sending data to server",e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get response when response code is HTTP_OK.

the problem with your code is that it is not fetching the actual object from the server, it is only fetching the response code...for fetching the actual data/object, you need to create a buffered reader and get the input stream as below.

try this:

```
int httpResult = connection.getResponseCode();
Log.d("Test","http response code: "+httpResult);

if(httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    Log.d("Test",IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream()));
    Log.d("Test", "result read");

    //get response
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }

    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

You might need to use json converter to convert response string to json.

Comment: I thought `IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream())` was supposed to do what your addition to the code does. Plus, the php script prints the post information to the error log, and it prints an empty line with the above android code, but when I use a command line tool like `curl` to send the data, the data is printed to the log. I'm reasonably certain that the data is not being sent correctly.